# On click of button app is not launching

Tags: android

I combined two android studio apps.

One I converted to a library and in it I created a new Activity and added two buttons.

On click of one button my library app is launching, but one more app is not opening. I used intent here.

Can anyone help me? Here is my intent program:

```
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("object.zhdbzx.client/object.zhdbzx.client.Splash"));
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent); ;
        }
    });
```

If this app is already on the phone then its opening.

Comment: "If this app is already on the phone then its opening." What you mean this like 2nd app is installed in your device then it is opening.So for this you have to create 2nd app as a library and added to the first app. So when we click on the first app(like button click) then it will open the second app.